# Inner join where a particular column needs to be distinct

Tags: sql-server

I'm writing the following stored procedure:

```
SELECT invite.sender_id,
       invite.invite_msg_text,
       invite.date_sent,
       person.name_first,
       person.name_last,
       member.member_image_url
FROM   invite
       INNER JOIN person
               ON invite.sender_id = person.person_id
       INNER JOIN member
               ON invite.sender_id = member.person_id
WHERE  invite.invite_status = 'P'
       AND invite.recipient_email = @recipientEmail
ORDER  BY invite.date_sent DESC
```

but I want to return rows with distinct sender_id/person_id. Right now it will return duplicate rows if a user has sent more than one invite. Is it possible to return only distinct rows based on sender_id/person_id

Comment: Can you share the schema of invite, person and member?

Comment: Sure it is possible. You could add distinct to your query. I suspect however that isn't going to get what you want. When you have duplicates which value(s) do you want for the other columns? MIN? MAX? Aggregation is the easiest way to do this but not really sure what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Do you want the most recent invite sent?

Comment: Yes, the most recent invite sent would be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you the most recent invite sent by sender_id.. Using row_number to determine which was sent last.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT invite.sender_id,
           invite.invite_msg_text,
           invite.date_sent,
           person.name_first,
           person.name_last,
           member.member_image_url,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY invite.sender_id ORDER BY invite.date_sent DESC) Rn 
    FROM   invite
           INNER JOIN person
                   ON invite.sender_id = person.person_id
           INNER JOIN member
                   ON invite.sender_id = member.person_id
    WHERE  invite.invite_status = 'P'
           AND invite.recipient_email = @recipientEmail
) t
WHERE t.RN = 1
ORDER BY t.date_sent DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT invite.sender_id, invite.invite_msg_text, invite.date_sent, person_a.name_first, person_a.name_last, member.member_image_url
FROM invite
INNER JOIN (select person_id, max(name_first) as name_first,max(name_last) as name_last from person group by person_id) as person_a 
ON person_a.person_id = invite.sender_id
```

Should accomplish what you seem to be after.

Comment: And of course, add in your later joins and group by, ect